RJ45 Wall Plate and Patchpanel Color Coding
Bought a VCELINK Wall Plate , used the T568A ( White Blue , Blue , White Green , Green ,
White Orange , Orange , White Brown , Brown . 5 4 1 2 3 6 7 8 ) .
Now I have a Patchpanel from DeleyCON . There I also have T568A and it says :
White Green , Green , White Orange, Orange , White Brown , Brown , White Blue , Blue . 1 2 3 6 7 8 5 4 .
I am no longer sure about this. DeleyCON Wall Plate says for T568A : White Green , Green , Blue, White Blue , White Orange , Orange , White Brown , Brown . 1 2 4 5 3 6 7 8 .
Which is correct ?
I would like to use the correct layout for the existing Wall Plates on the Patchpanel ,
for this T568A ( White Blue , Blue , White Green , Green ,
White Orange , Orange , White Brown , Brown . 5 4 1 2 3 6 7 8 ) . Can someone tell me what is the correct coloring on the Patchpanel?
Thank you!

The standards determine how the cable pairs/ colors must align with the pins, those on the front of the patch panel, where you plug in the RJ45 connectors.
There is no requirement for any particular (matching) layout of the rear ; the punchdown section. As long as the internal wiring from the punchdown section ends up in the correct pin on the front. When the rear says T568A , assume that when the pairs/colour strands of your cables are placed as instructed there, they will align with the correct pins for T568A on the front.
See the random pictures below for different T568A  rear layout approaches from different vendors.




Ah okay, got confused there . So that means if I follow the Color Coding on both Wall Panel and Patch Panel for A it should probably work.  I will connect one and use a Cable Tester to check . Thank you.

Indeed, follow the instructions for each piece of kit and everything should be well./
